# What type of control unit do Sandy Bridge processors use?

Tags: microprocessor, intel

I'm doing a class project about the Intel Pentium G620 processor and I need to know the type of control unit used in Sandy Bridge processors (at least in the Pentium G620). Is it microprogrammed or hardwired?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky to map a classification from the early 80s directly on to a modern system, but Intel systems are definitely "microprogrammed" to some extent: they have a microcode, and occasionally they ship updates to the microcode.

Comment: yeah... I'd argue it's not even trivial to say that hey, this area here in the block diagram (leave alone on the die) is the Control Unit. IMHO, not an extremely helpful term to describe or understand how a pipelined processor works. "The wholeness of things in a processor that decide on what operates how" breaks down, very quickly, when one realizes that things like conditional moves, prefetching, speculative execution … are done by the respective element, and not by one central all-knowing mechanism.